# EchoSign: Extra signature box appears while sending out to multiple signers

Tags: echosign

I'm trying to create an url widget using below code to allow the document be signed by multiple signers. But when I upload the document, an extra signature box appears at the beginning, then the remaining signature boxes appear for each email address I mention in the `WidgetCreationInfo.CounterSigners` property. I need to remove the extra signature box from the document.

```
var senderInfo = new com.echosign.secure22.SenderInfo();
        senderInfo.email = "abx@xyz.com";
        senderInfo.password = "******";

        var widgetInfo = new com.echosign.secure22.WidgetCreationInfo();
        widgetInfo.name = "test widget";

        widgetInfo.fileInfos = new EchoSign.com.echosign.secure22.FileInfo[1];
        widgetInfo.fileInfos[0] = new EchoSign.com.echosign.secure22.FileInfo();
        widgetInfo.fileInfos[0].file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        widgetInfo.fileInfos[0].fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);

        widgetInfo.callbackInfo = new com.echosign.secure22.CallbackInfo();
        widgetInfo.callbackInfo.signedDocumentUrl = redirectUrl;
        widgetInfo.signatureFlow = EchoSign.com.echosign.secure22.SignatureFlow.SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED;

        widgetInfo.counterSigners = new com.echosign.secure22.RecipientInfo[2];
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[0] = new com.echosign.secure22.RecipientInfo();
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[0].email = "abc@gmail.com";
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[0].role = com.echosign.secure22.RecipientRole.SIGNER;
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[0].roleSpecified = true;
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[1] = new com.echosign.secure22.RecipientInfo();
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[1].email = "xyz@yahoo.com";
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[1].role = com.echosign.secure22.RecipientRole.SIGNER;
        widgetInfo.counterSigners[1].roleSpecified = true;

        var result = ES22.createEmbeddedWidget(apiKey, senderInfo, widgetInfo);
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

The first signature block is for the widget signer. The rest of the recipients you have added are counter signers and would need to sign once the first signer of the widget signs. If you simply need a document to be signed by multiple signers, you can create a normal agreement instead of a widget. If yow want to host the signing page, you can use [eSign services API](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/_0_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9) to retrieve the signing URL of the signers in the agreement. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tushit for your response. Can you please let me know the difference between normal agreement and widget? Just to let you know, my requirement is to create a process that will upload a large number of documents to be singed by different companies. 2 signers from each company will sign an agreement. Then I will need to track the signing status programmatically in my system to display the status of each agreement. Can you please guide me to the next step how I can use the normal agreements?

Comment: Widgets are forms that you can host on your website where users can come to and fill and sign. The other workflow is that you send a document to multiple users who then receive a mail with a URL specific to each user which they can open and sign. Please refer to the agreement endpoint at https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/agreements/. You can call POST /agreements to send the document(s) for signing and either specify a callback URL to track agreement status or call GET /agreements/{agreementId} to get the agreement status. Let me know if this helps. Thanks